# Change background for specific rows in datagrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a datagrid "Funds" bind to a listcollectionview.

I want to highlight specific rows in datagrid based on few rules. The fundGroupsList is the list of group names. The rule1 is to find the misalignment within members of a group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the ways to do that is to create a **boolean property** (ex. **IsRule1Failed**) in Entries and save the **fail result foreach row**.

Then, in XAML use DataTriggers to change the background color.

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
          <Style.Triggers>
             <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                 <Setter Property="Background" Value="BurlyWood" />
             </Trigger>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.IsRule1Failed}" Value="True">
                 <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
             </DataTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
 </DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But, can you elaborate a little more. My problem here is datagrid is bound to listcollectionview due to which I am not able to access individual row. Initially I tried changing the background using CellValuePresenter but then the DataGridRow object is always set to null in that case

Comment: I see that you are using PortfolioTable.PortfolioData as your ItemsSource, can you post the code where you create the collection and add items?

Comment: Can you also add the code for Add() method and the piece of code where there is something like PortfolioData = new ....

Comment: Add() method refers to the add method in observablecollection. The class FundsTable is extending the observablecollection class.
Also I had changed the Binding. I did not change it after changing the class name to FundsTable.
Currently there is no PortfolioData in the code. The class itself is an observablecollection of type Entries.

Comment: Ok, I think I got that part, not sure how much help I can be, what did you do with the Binding?

Comment: I just left it as Binding; ItemsSource="{Binding}"

Comment: Oh, I totally misunderstood that part. Well, theoretically it should work, the  DataContext property in xaml will give you the access to individual row

Comment: Can u explain a little more on how to do that. How do I change the property as the observablecollection here is the class. I know something like FundsTable[i].isRule1Failed = true, will not work;
How can I do that ?

Comment: In FillFunds() call Rule1() method to determine if it failes, and set true/false where you create new Entries() on the last line Add(new Entries { isRule1Failed = rule1Result ....};

Comment: I will be calling Rule1 on datagrid. How can I give it in FillFunds() as that method will be adding individual entries. And also this has to be performed on all the funds in the grid so I can not do while adding each entry.

Comment: I definitely see that, than in Rule1() when you are doing for (groupList) you will be having the access to individual entry (set it isRule1Failed there) while still evaluating the whole list of funds.

Answer (score -3):

You can also simply change the CSS Class of the row.
GridView.SelectedRowStyle.CssClass = "selectedrow";